# Overriding Tag level external CSS of a Flex control

Tags: css, apache-flex, controls, skinning

I have an external CSS file which defines the style for the Button tag.

```
Button {fontSize 11;  blah...}
```

I'm trying to override this style for the buttons of a ToggleButtonBar:

```
<mx:ToggleButtonBar dataProvider="{pm.portalNavigation}" fontSize="16" />
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.  The fontSize stays at 11.  How can I override the external CSS to resize the buttons in my ButtonBar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set the buttonStyleName property, so

```
<mx:ToggleButtonBar buttonStyleName="myButtonStyle">...</mx:ToggleButtonBar>

.myButtonStyle{
   font-size: 16;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess from the [Flex documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/langref/mx/controls/ButtonBar.html#propertySummary)...

```
<mx:ToggleButtonBar dataProvider="{pm.portalNavigation}" styleDeclaration="font-size:16pt !important" />
```

Comment: And Flex CSS doesn't support !important